# Memory warning when loading google map in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

In my app UIWebView loads Google maps, while using this 
Direction url == http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&geocode=&saddr=37.774930,-122.419415&daddr=37.7655277,-122.421811&ie=UTF8&z=12,

it throws "Received memory warning" and my app crash.

UIWebview is a subview of UIView in my view controller. I took it as a IBOutlet.

Pls help me with this, it creates lots of trouble for my app.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

.h
///----
    #import

```
@interface WebsiteViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

{

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

}

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

.m
///---

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"url"];
[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
[request release]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your sooner reply, but memory warning is still as it was.. Memory warning occurs when webView load google map and create ROUTE between two locations. And in few secs my app is on the way to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app actually crashing (does the Xcode debugger catch it? can you post the stack trace of the thread which crashed), or is it being shut down by the OS for using too much memory?

You might also try reproducing the crash with NSZombieEnabled - check the Xcode docs for the details on how to do this.